# Json_encode and json_decode not working in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i want to insert value through Json_encode through controller but json_encode() not working in yii2.

```
json_encode();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working in yii2`? `json_encode()` is native PHP function, so how it can't work in yii2?

Comment: Show your real problem and not a generic code  only ...

Answer (score 0):

You can test `json_encode()` in a controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $json = json_encode(['key'=>'value']);
    echo $json;
}
```

The result should be:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

`json_encode()` won't be unworked without an error such as no `php-json` extension, and it is a PHP function which works the same in Yii2.